# rvest - Extract data from OMIM

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

EDIT: After some research and help from others, I figured what I was trying to do is not ethical. I asked for OMIM API permission from OMIM website and advise the same to anyone who needs to do same stuff.

I am quite inexperienced in HTML.

Using some keywords like 'ciliary' and 'primary' I want to go into OMIM, get into first 5 links listed, save text within those links and scrape data based on keywords like 'homozygous', 'heterozygous' etc.

What I have done so far:

```
rvestedOMIM <- function() {

  clinicKeyWord1 <- c('primary', 'ciliary')
  OMIM1 <- paste0("https://www.omim.org/search/?index=entry&start=1&limit=10&sort=score+desc%2C+prefix_sort+desc&search=", clinicKeyWord1[1], "+", clinicKeyWord1[2])
  webpage <- read_html(OMIM1)
  rank_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.mim-hint')
  # Go into first 5 links and extract the data based on keywords
  allLinks <- rank_data_html[grep('a href',rank_data_html)]
  allLinks <- allLinks[grep('omim', allLinks)]

}
```

At the moment, I am stuck at going through the links listed in the first OMIM search (with 'primary' and 'ciliary' keywords). allLinks object within the function I wrote is intended to extract the links

e.g.

## 244400. CILIARY DYSKINESIA, PRIMARY, 1; CILD1

(https://www.omim.org/entry/244400?search=ciliary%20primary&highlight=primary%20ciliary)

## 608644. CILIARY DYSKINESIA, PRIMARY, 3; CILD3

(https://www.omim.org/entry/608644?search=ciliary%20primary&highlight=primary%20ciliary)

Even if I could scrape the OMIM id in the links 244400 or 608644, I can navigate through the links by myself which is a workaround I thought in case I couldn't scrape  that yields the full link.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You might want (well, you might just be a content thief and not care) to read this: https://www.omim.org/robots.txt

Comment: Thanks :) I was hoping to figure this out rather in legal terms.. But thanks really

Comment: Smileys don't make unethical things OK.

Comment: No they don't.. Using OMIM API with correct permissions might though. Which I asked for from OMIM people and waiting for an answer.